# Logo above Navbar

Tags: html, css

i am curios on how i would get a logo above the Navbar
Like this:
[image]

I am not really sure how i can achieve this, i basically want the navbar to not be at the very top, but have the logo-top at the top of the site, then have the Navbar centered on the Logo, while the Logo is above the Navbar, so basically a part of the Navbar should be hidden behind it, and then align the buttons left and right of it

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  
  .navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .content {
    padding: 16px;
  }
  
  .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    width: 10% !important;
    height: 10% !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px !important;  /* 50% of your logo width */
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
      <div class="navbar" align="center">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="5%; height=5%; z-index: 10">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Server 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content" align="center">
            <a href="#"> Server 2</a>
            <a href="#"> Server 1</a>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <a href="#news">Discord</a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex box model and play around with the negative margin on the logo (I use `.middle-logo` class in here as an example):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.logo {
  width: 10% !important;
  height: 10% !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
  /* 50% of your logo width */
  display: block;
}

.middle-logo {
  height: 66px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 66px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" align="center">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/107/759/png-transparent-circle-white-circle-white-monochrome-black-thumbnail.png" width="5%; height=5%; z-index: 10" class="middle-logo">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Server 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" align="center">
      <a href="#"> Server 2</a>
      <a href="#"> Server 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#news">Discord</a>
</div>
```

I used a random width/height here though, but the important part here is to use that negative margin, you could just adjust it according to your need

Comment: Center alignment of the flexbox children would be better than negative margins. Ideally layout doesn't hinge on image size, for example, but works regardless of image size.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the layer of your image/logo with z-index in css

Comment: Answers should be more specific. Please see [answer].